# Is there a way to smooth the text in plots, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to smooth the text in plots, in Matlab?

By text I mean all the text added to a plot with commands such as
xlabel, ylabel, title, etc...

Thanks

Comment: Is it critical that these plots look good *inside MATLAB*? If you only want them to look good once exported then you can use, e.g., [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig).

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use the `painters` renderer, which is a vector renderer.  The `zbuffer` and `openGL` renderers are raster renderers, which really degrades the quality of the text.

EDIT: I just came upon a [blog post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update/#more-3789) from Undocumented Matlab.  Apparently MathWorks has been working on an update to the handle graphics engine for a while, and has it included in the code base as a silent option.

I made a couple test plots and for the raster `openGL` renderer, the fonts are properly smoothed and the lines look very good.  For the vector `painters` renderer, the lines are still a little jagged, but they look much, much, much better than before.  Unfortunately, it looks like it also breaks `export_fig` and the internal `print` function, at least as far as producing externally editable pdf files is concerned.

If you're only interested in screen graphics, though, you should definitely give it a look.

Comment: I changed the renderer to painters and it did improve the text rendering, but now my lines that I was drawing are aliased again. This is the command for the line plot(x,y5,'LineWidth',2,'LineSmoothing','on','Color','r');

Comment: I have never used the `LineSmoothing` command, and I don't see it in my documentation (MATLAB 2013b).  When I try using it, it automatically switches to the `OpenGL` renderer.